# is singular and is home not working

Tags: conditional-tags

I am creating a theme and i have added custom hooks to make the developement easier. 
when using the code in functions it works in all pages. the code is below

```
add_action('before_footer','post_prev_nex');
function post_prev_nex(){
    the_post_navigation();
}
```

But when i try to put a conditional, it doesnt work.

```
if (is_singular()) {
    add_action('before_footer','post_prev_nex');
function post_prev_nex(){
    the_post_navigation();
}
}
```

what is the problem here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put condition inside your function:

```
add_action('before_footer','post_prev_nex');
function post_prev_nex() {
    if (is_singular())
       the_post_navigation();
}
```

In your version `is_singular()` is executed when `functions.php` file is loaded, not while displaying the page.

Comment: thanks it worked. i will accept answer as soon as i am able to accept it

Comment: You might want to mention why that is, namely that when `functions.php` WP hasn't figured out what content is going to be loaded yet, and so it doesn't know if it's singular or not

Answer (score 1):

`is_singular()` won't work when placed directly into functions.php or a plugin, because WordPress has not determined what content is actually being requested when it loads themes and plugins. You need to perform the check later by putting it inside an action callback that occurs after WordPress has determined what the content is.

The simplest solution then is just to use the function inside the callback:

```
function post_prev_nex() {
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        the_post_navigation();
    }
}
add_action('before_footer','post_prev_nex');
```